# INSERT IF condition met

Tags: mysql

```
IF (( SELECT param FROM changes WHERE type = 'uptime' AND website_id = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 ) != 'up' )
    INSERT INTO changes ( website_id, timestamp, type, param ) VALUES ( 1, NOW(), 'uptime', 'up' )
END IF;
```

This appears to be an incorrect syntax. How else can I make this work in a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you reading param record outside the query using IF instead of just adding it in the WHERE Condition? If you do it like this then you can just Insert the complete query, if the query returns something your data will be inserted, if your query returns nothing then nothing would be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO changes ( website_id, timestamp, type, param )
     SELECT 1, NOW(), 'uptime', 'up'
       FROM changes 
      WHERE type = 'uptime' AND website_id = 1 AND param != 'up' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You know, actually you don't need that ORDER BY, i removed it from that code.

Comment: Something more you should take into account: I see your IF was checking if last record (from many) had param != 'up', but this code I posted will search for param != 'up' for any record, not just last one, do you understand what i mean? If you really need to check only against last record (in desc order) then this code won't work as it is now.

Comment: Yes, I've corrected the query to account for the param and sorting to get the last record. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`changes` seems to be a table for logging events. Given all the variations of `INSERT`it is not possible to do it. You can try using `STORED PROCEDURE` to achieve it. You can do something like following:

```
select param into @last_param from changes where website_id = 1 and type = 'uptime' limit 1;
```

Now @last_param will contain `up` or `down`. In the next statement can be conditional on if `last_param` is up or down.